# JPA fetch join when property is only in some subclasses

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Is there a way to do something like this

```
select a from A a join fetch a.b
```

when `a.b` only exists for some subclasses of `A`?

where I have

```
@Entity
class A {
}

@Entity
class SubA extends A {
  @OneToMany
  List<B> b;
}
```

In other words, I'd like to fetch-join the @OneToMany collection `a.b` only if `a instanceof SubA` is true.

Is this possible?  Or is there a better way to avoid the n-plus-one select problem for a collection?   What I'm really after is trying to prevent doing a round trip for each `B` in the collection - fetch join seems to work well for that.

I am using EclipseLink but prefer JPA standard whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'better way' (with Eclipselink, anyhow) looks like it's to use batch fetch instead, either by annotating the `@OneToMany` with `@BatchFetch` or adding a query hint.